# Magento 2 In product page, when display message if stock < 0?

Tags: magento2.3, catalog

I want to display on the right of "In stock" --> "**The delivery time will be 15 days**"

Comment: You will have to do customization for that.

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{theme-name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

```
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span> <span class="delivery-inf"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('The delivery time will be 15 days') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```